# Arranging buttons on the left and image button on the right in the same row and same background

Tags: android, button, imagebutton, tablelayout, tablerow

Need help for arranging button on the left and image button on the right in the same row and same background. Below is my entire XML code. Please take a look :)
Currently using table layout and linear layout. 
Thank You

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" >

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/TableLayout01"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#E7FEFF" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="#FFFFF0"
                android:text="Opp SAFRA Tampines"
                android:textSize="22dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:width="1000dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_height="2dip"
            android:background="#FF0000" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal" 
            android:background="#E7FEFF"    >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/5"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:background="#E7FEFF"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="  5" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/chart"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/chart" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TableRow>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text02"
                android:background="#E7FEFF"
                android:text="  Pasir Ris Int"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:width="850px" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>

            <TextView
                android:background="#E7FEFF"
                android:text="  15:25   15:36    15:47"
                android:textSize="13dp" />
        </TableRow>

        <View
            android:layout_height="2dip"
            android:background="#FF0000" />

        <TableRow>

            <TextView
                android:background="#E7FEFF"
                android:stretchColumns="2"
                android:text="  15"
                android:textSize="18dp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>

            <TextView
                android:background="#E7FEFF"
                android:text="  Tampines Int"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:width="850px" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>

            <TextView
                android:background="#E7FEFF"
                android:text="  15:23   15:28    15:30"
                android:textSize="13dp" />
        </TableRow>

        <View
            android:layout_height="2dip"
            android:background="#FF0000" />

        <TableRow>

            <TextView
                android:background="#E7FEFF"
                android:stretchColumns="2"
                android:text="  21"
                android:textSize="18dp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>

            <TextView
                android:background="#E7FEFF"
                android:text="  Pasir Ris Int"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:width="850px" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>

            <TextView
                android:background="#E7FEFF"
                android:text="  15:23   15:26    15:39"
                android:textSize="13dp" />
        </TableRow>

        <View
            android:layout_height="2dip"
            android:background="#FF0000" />

        <TableRow>

            <TextView
                android:background="#E7FEFF"
                android:stretchColumns="2"
                android:text="  23"
                android:textSize="18dp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>

            <TextView
                android:background="#E7FEFF"
                android:text="  Tampines Int"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:width="850px" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>

            <TextView
                android:background="#E7FEFF"
                android:text="  15:29   15:30    15:39"
                android:textSize="13dp" />
        </TableRow>

        <View
            android:layout_height="2dip"
            android:background="#FF0000" />
    </TableLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put them in a Linear Layout!

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/5"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:background="#E7FEFF"
            android:text="  5" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/buslogo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/chart" />
</LinearLayout>
```

If you want each of them to take up half the space, just add

```
android:layout_weight="1"
```

to both the button and the ImageButton.

Comment: there is error..when save, R file gone which means my xml layout got problem

Comment: edit your question and add the ENTIRE xml file you tried that just gave you that problem

Comment: i have done editing and paste whole xml code @Alex K

Comment: @GlynnNeo great. I think the issue is that you got rid of the TableRow you had before. Go ahead and put that linear layout INSIDE of a tablerow.